# OpenCV resize memory leak

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, memory-leaks

I have a little bigger application that was generating memory leaks. I could nail them down to a `cv::resize` call. These leaks are not causing guaranteed crashes, but instead it seemed to be system dependent. It crashed on one, but not the other, "only" giving a first chance exception there.

I reduced the code drastically to just this (**this is not crashing**):

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    _CrtMemState s1, s2, s3;
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&s1);

    cv::Mat src = cv::imread("C:\\Users\\Gunnar\\Pictures\\test.jpg");

    cv::Size targetSize(600, 800);

    cv::Mat dst(targetSize, src.type());

    cv::resize(src, dst, targetSize, 0, 0, cv::INTER_CUBIC);

    cv::imshow("resize test", dst);

    cv::waitKey(0);

    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&s2);

    if (_CrtMemDifference(&s3, &s1, &s2))
    {
        _CrtMemDumpStatistics(&s3);
        _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Still I do get memory leaks on this on both systems.

This is using OpenCV 3, Windows 7 as developement system and Windows 10 as the other, both 64 bit. This is compiled for 64 bit.

I'm pretty sure this is not a false positive since it would not crash in my application otherwise, but I can't seem to figure out why this is happening or what I need to do to fix this. Does anybody have an idea what is going on here?

Edit:
Was about to edit the result of the `if`, but SO told me `Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 49686`, so here is just the `_CrtMemDumpStatistics`:

```
0 bytes in 0 Free Blocks.
2617124 bytes in 21 Normal Blocks.
176508 bytes in 154 CRT Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 Ignore Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 Client Blocks.
Largest number used: 2899588 bytes.
Total allocations: 3113364 bytes.
```

Edit 2:
I'm working in Visual Studio 2013 (Compile as default). OpenCV 3.0.0.
/MDd for Debug and /MD for Release.

Debug Linker Command Line:

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\Gunnar\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ResizeTest\x64\Debug\ResizeTest.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\Gunnar\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ResizeTest\x64\Debug\ResizeTest.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "opencv_ts300d.lib" "opencv_world300d.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\Users\Gunnar\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ResizeTest\x64\Debug\ResizeTest.pgd" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\ResizeTest.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"E:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc12\lib" /TLBID:1
```

Release Linker Command Line:

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\Gunnar\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ResizeTest\x64\Release\ResizeTest.exe" /MANIFEST /LTCG /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\Gunnar\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ResizeTest\x64\Release\ResizeTest.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "opencv_ts300.lib" "opencv_world300.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MACHINE:X64 /OPT:REF /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"C:\Users\Gunnar\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ResizeTest\x64\Release\ResizeTest.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Release\ResizeTest.exe.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"E:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc12\lib" /TLBID:1
```

Edit 3:
These are the exception messages I get when debugging my bigger application:

```
VERIFIER STOP 0000000000000900: pid 0x1204: A heap allocation was leaked. 

000001DF41222800 : Address of the leaked allocation. Run !heap -p -a <address> to get additional information about the allocation.
000001DF317DFFB0 : Address to the allocation stack trace. Run dps <address> to view the allocation stack.
000001DF415C1FD8 : Address of the owner dll name. Run du <address> to read the dll name.
00007FF8AA7D0000 : Base of the owner dll. Run .reload <dll_name> = <address> to reload the owner dll. Use 'lm' to get more information about the loaded and unloaded modules.
```

Comment: if there are crashes, what error message do you get? What exactly do you mean by memory leak, memory that isn't freed? How does that relate to the crashes? One common problem is to link debug libraries to release build or vice-versa, which often leads to crashes.

Comment: In what way are the leaks related to the crashes? Eventual out of memory issues?

Comment: Also, what exactly are you measuring there? At the time you take the second checkpoint, you still have the two `cv::Mat` objects in scope. Why not measure just around the `cv::resize`?

Comment: There are a lot of this _memory leak reports_ for some OpenCV functions... Most of them are false positives, the others are due to OpenCV implementation. In any case, they are not a problem. So just live with them, and no one is harmed ;D

Comment: @Micka The crash messages were `A heap allocation is leaking` and they were pointing to the resize.

Comment: my guess: you are using the wrong libraries for your build. Can you add information about the used compiler and, if possible, the linker command line?

Comment: @DanMašek In my other application where the problem originated I had the `MemState` just around the resize. Also if I do it here it gives the same.

Comment: @Micka I added info, I hope that is what you wanted.

Comment: The above short code doesn't crash, it does in my other application pointing to the resize (I have exactly one). That is probably because of the size of the programs. The bigger one just uses more memory and therefore runs out of memory with those leaks.

Comment: @Miki I would ignore them - if my application wasn't crashing.

Comment: Side comment: having hard coded filenames (and paths) is very bad practice...

Comment: @kebs That is just for this test, my program doesn't have this.

Comment: @GunnarB. I'm fairly confident that your app is crashing because of something else ;D

Comment: @Miki But why is it throwing the exception directly on the `cv::resize`? Like `WinDbg` is giving me the exact same line too.

Comment: @GunnarB. Start from the consideration that `resize` is not bugged, otherwise almost every OpenCV code would fail, which isn't the case. most probably you have some problems with your pointers / Mat views on user allocated areas / whatever, and that problem just reveals at the `resize`, but has always been there

Comment: in your real code: can you imshow the input image of the resize at the position where it crashes before the resize call? Does that show an image? (call waitKey(0) before the resize.

Comment: @Micka Well, I can't test that right now, but I'm pretty sure it does because I can continue the debugging. It gives about 5 or 6 consecutive exception messages at that point and after that the program continues and finishes with the expected result. Obviously that requires running the program with a debugger.